# How to log on to Windows Server 2012 if password has expired

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

I have a Windows Server 2012 instance on which there is only one administrator account (which is not the default admin account) and the password for this account has expired. The default admin account is disabled. How can I (remotely) regain access to the server? I currently have no access whatsoever.

I tried the `enablecredsspsupport:i:0` option in RD client, but it tells me that the server requires NLA which is disabled on my system.

Comment: So is it safe to say that this server is not joined to a domain?

Comment: @wrieedx very safe. Yes.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done via RDP itself!

> In the protocol specification for CredSSP, there is no reference to
>   the ability to change the user's password while NLA is running.
>   Therefore, the observed behavior can be considered "by design."
>
> CredSSP is the underlying technology that enables NLA, and it does not
>   support password changes. Therefore, password changes are not enabled
>   in MSTSC. Other RD clients that support NLA should be unable to change
>   the user’s password.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2648402/you-cannot-change-an-expired-user-account-password-in-a-remote-desktop

As they suggest, enable changing the password via RDWeb is an option. Another option i have seen is changing the password via Exchange webmail.

Comment: Except I don't have access to any of these enabled and they require some setup AFAICT, which I cannot perform since I don't have access to the server. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a local administrator password reset boot USB.  That would also allow you to enable the built in administrator account.
A lot of people like [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/resetting-windows-password/)

Comment: We're talking about a remote virtual server in a datacenter. I was hoping to find a way to fix it myself, but as it seems, there's no other option than to contact the datacenter and ask them to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the password with [pspasswd](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pspasswd):

```
pspasswd \\server -u user -p oldpsswd user newpsswd
```

Comment: It doesn't work, seems to think that `Error changing password: The RPC server is unavailable.` I can't imagine Windows would have such an obvious flaw, there has to be a way to do this...